# How to submit an abstract?

Tags: conference, computer-science, abstract

I wrote a paper that I wish to propose to a certain CS conference. Two of the deadlines mentioned on the Important Dates page on the conference's website are: Abstract submission and Paper submission.

My paper already has an abstract section.

I know what a paper is supposed to look like, but what is an abstract, as a separate entity, supposed to look like? Do I simply copy the abstract from my paper? Is it supposed to be submitted as a pdf document? Do I need to add a title? My name?

Could someone please post a link to an example abstract document that is adequate to be submitted to an abstract submission deadline for a conference?

Comment: Go to last year's conference site and usually there are plenty of abstracts and publications there already to follow. Every conference and every field has a different format and expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer 1:** Go to the paper submission web site and click on *"submit abstract"*; you will be redirected to a web form where you can enter title, authors, and abstract. It will tell you the preferred format for each of these.

**Answer 2:**
Conference organizers split the abstract submission and paper submission deadlines so that program committee members can already select the papers they want to review while the authors may still be working on the paper itself. Typically, the PC members see the titles and abstracts in some conference organization system such as EasyChair where they can bid on the submissions. The most convenient format for this purpose is typically *plain text*. In fact, I don't remember any conference that asked for something else. Some very restricted form of HTML might also be possible, but PDF is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Do I simply copy the abstract from my paper? Is it supposed to be submitted as a pdf document? Do I need to add a title? My name? Yes, no, yes and usually no.